# In Kotlin how Immutable parameters affect space complexity if you have to copy the input every time to modify it?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, immutability, space-complexity

In Kotlin, function parameters are immutable, so you cannot modify the parameter in the code without making a copy first, does this affect space complexity, and does it prevent in-place modification, thus preventing it from having O(1) constant? What is the solution to this?

```
fun replaceFirstElement(nums: IntArray, number: Int) {
    // not working
    nums[0] = number
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `// not working`? That code seems to work as intended. — Also, while you cannot reassign the function parameters, the objects they reference _can_ be mutable; and Kotlin arrays are always mutable. So this code is O(1), doing no allocation (except for a stack frame with references to the params).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array in Kotlin is always mutable, also when handed over as argument to a function. It is fixed-sized, but the elements are mutable:

```
fun replaceFirstElement(nums: IntArray, number: Int) {
  nums[0] = number
}

val intArray = IntArray(10) { it + 1 }

replaceFirstElement(intArray, 99)

intArray.forEach { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
99
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

This also applies to the other array types, and to the mutable collection like MutableList, MutableMap, etc.

Comment: What I mean wasn't the immutabilty of an IntArray, but the fact that you cannot modify the parameter passed directly, let me modify my code a bit

Comment: I revert it. The question is still valid